# Qualitative difference between bremsstrahlung and thermal bremsstrahlung

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, thermal-radiation, ions

Hopefully this is an easy question. I hear the terms bremsstrahlung and thermal bremsstrahlung being used. However, I, incorrectly, thought that they were used interchangeably.

So, what is te qualitative difference between bremsstrahlung and thermal bremsstrahlung?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in population sizes. With (just) bremsstrahlung, you're talking about *a single* electron passing near an atom. This results in the typical expression of the radiated power,
$$
P_{br}\sim \gamma^4\left(\dot{\boldsymbol\beta}^2+\frac{\boldsymbol\beta\cdot\dot{\boldsymbol\beta}}{1-\beta^2}\right)
$$
with $\gamma$ the Lorentz factor and $\boldsymbol\beta=\mathbf v/c$. This leads to $P\propto a^2$ (with $a=\dot\beta$), so the emission depends on the deceleration of the electron as it passes the atom.

With *thermal* bremsstrahlung, you're talking about a (large) *population* of electrons that follow the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) (a *thermal* population since the electron distribution depends on $T$) and are undergoing the bremsstrahlung process. This leads to the power of
$$
P_{ff}\sim T^{1/2}
$$
so the emission here depends on the temperature of the gas cloud.

For more information, you can take a look at Chapter 5 of [Rybicki & Lightman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471827592) (Amazon link), which discusses single electron, thermal & relativistic bremsstrahlung emissions processes.