# How is black body radiation from sample eliminated when measuring absorption coefficient?

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, absorption, infrared-radiation

I wonder how absorption spectra of a sample (e.g. gas with some $CO_2$ absorbing strongly at $\approx 15\mu m$) is measured by IR spectroscopy, thereby having in mind the following arrangement, consistent of a source, a detector and a sample of optical thickness $\tau$ for a given wavelength:

[image]

There is a general radiation law I learned (*). It says, that (without scattering) spectral intensity after passing a medium is the original intensity attenuated by absorption plus the emitted radiation from the sample itself:

$$ I_\nu (\tau) = I_\nu (0) \cdot e^{- \tau } + I_\nu^B\cdot \left(1-e^{-\tau}  \right)  \tag{1}$$

where $I_\nu^B$ is the Planck radiation intensity from the sample at a given temperature.

Now, for weak absorption $\tau \ll 1$ this can be approximated as

$$ I_\nu (\tau) = I_\nu (0) \cdot (1- \tau ) + I_\nu^B\cdot \tau  \tag{2}$$

so what I would measure as the drop in intensity at the detector would be

$$ I_\nu (0) - I_\nu (\tau) =  (I_\nu(0) - I_\nu^B) \cdot \tau  \tag{3}$$

What I'm interested in is, however

$$ I_\nu(0) \cdot \alpha \cdot \Delta x = I_\nu(0) \cdot \tau  \tag{4}$$

because this gives my absorption coefficient $\alpha$.

It seems to me, that the absorption is always a little bit underestimated because of the black-body part. So how do I get rid of it? Is it just neglected? Or is there a flaw in my whole consideration?

(*) K. N. Liou, An Introduction to Atmospheric Radiation, Chapter 1.4

Comment: Related: [How does radiation become black-body radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645671/247642), [How is light emitted by an incandescent lamp?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639995/247642), [Black body vs. Thermal radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644253/247642)